# Back Button in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sidebar

I use the `SWRevealViewController` to *add a sidebar menu* in my app. I have my `SideBarViewController` where I set the view controller, lets say `OptionAViewController`. I use the reveal view controller segue to open this new view `OptionAViewController`. From `OptionAViewController` I want to implement a back button to return to `SideBarViewController`.

Here is how I set the `optionAViewController`. This works.

```
//SideBarViewController

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
    SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

    swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

        UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        //[navController pushViewController:dvc animated: NO ];
        [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
    };
}
```

}

And this is how I am trying to implement the back button in `OptionAViewController`. I tried with `popViewController` but it crashes. I also tried other options but none of them is working. Do you know what should be the selector?

```
 //back button in ViewDidLoad (OptionAViewController)
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

Answer (score 2):

check this [reference link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) for better understanding the SWRevealViewController.

this will bring back your side menu.

```
[_menuButton addTarget:self.revealViewController action:@selector(revealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

do not forget to

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
```

in your view controller.

Comment: This bring back the side menu but with my current view (OptionAViewController) as a rear view. I want to implement a back button to go back to: SideBarViewController in the front and MainViewController in the rear side, the same it appears when I first press my sidebar icon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SWRevealViewController *reveal = self.revealViewController;
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reveal-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:reveal action:@selector(revealToggle:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtn;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbtn.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
```

And in @selector method:

```
-(void)goBack{
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope this works.